# How to use a different version of Command Line Tools while using Xcode 13

Tags: xcode, macos, react-native, xcode12, xcode13

I was using Xcode 12.4 with Command Line Tools 12.4, but I've seen other versions that I could choose in this screen shot.

However, now that my Mac was updated to Monterey, I'm forced to use Xcode 13 and I can't run my project anymore.

Can I change them to 12.4 and resolve my problem?

[screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mHxhI.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Xcode 12.X is not supported in macOS Monterey, the minimum supported version of Xcode in Monterey is 13.X